# Read uint8 from []byte without creating a bytes.Buffer

Tags: go, buffer

How to read a `unit8` from `[]byte` without creating a `bytes.Buffer`. The value has been written to the buffer like this,

```golang
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, uint32(1))
binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, uint8(1))
b := buf.Bytes()
```

While decoding, it can easily be done for `uint32`, like the following...

```golang
len := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b[:4])
```

But for the `uint8`, the only way to retrieve the value that I could come up with, is to create a buffer and then read the first byte,

```golang
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
_, err := buf.Write(b[4:5])
// error handling ...
id = buf.ReadByte()
```

It seems like there's no method in the `encoding/binary` pkg for `uint8` value retrieval. And I guess there's probably some good reason behind it.

Question: Is there any other way to read `uint8` from that `[]byte` without creating a `Buffer`??

Comment: Just use an index expression. `b[0]` It's hard to get simpler than that. Is there some non-obvious requirement I'm missing?

Comment: [`byte` is just an alias for `uint8`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types).

Answer (score 5):

Us an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) to get an single `uint8` from a slice.

```
len := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b[:4])
id := b[4]  // <-- index expression
```

Note that `byte` is an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) for `uint8`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant way that I found,

```golang
var len uint32
var id uint8
binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &len)
binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &id)

// this method doesn't need you to create a buffer for each value read
```